# How to consume all messages from begining from apache kafka using java

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to consume all messages from the beginning of a topic in Apache Kafka. I can consume messages which are producing at that moment. Here is my code for fetch messages.

```
 public void consume() {
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            System.out.printf("\"%s\"\n", record.value());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some idea on the use-case that you are trying to achieve? Or is it just an experiment that you're trying out?

Comment: I need to analyze the messages from Apache Kafka, but in the beginning, I need all the data from the start of the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After subscribing to the topic, you can use the `seekToBeginning` method in order to set the offset at the beginning of the topic partition. Of course, it's valid per partition because a topic with different partitions has different beginning offsets (if messages deletion happened).

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting, `auto.offset.reset=earliest`, try setting a new/random value for property `group.id` and give it a try. Also, if you are not interested in keeping track of consumer position but always want to start from the beginning, you can also set `enable.auto.commit=false` to avoid polluting the offsets topic.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The console consumer generates a random consumer group id in order to accomplish this and sets `auto.offset.reset=earliest`

Make sure that you close the consumer object to prevent adding lots of temporary consumer groups ids in Zookeeper